# Syncfusion PDFViewer does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I recently decided to use the PdfViewer Control in on of my features. I've included the dependencies as mentioned int the Documentation"

- Syncfusion.Compression.Base
- Syncfusion.Pdf.Base
- Syncfusion.PdfViewer.Wpf

This is the namespace registered:

```
xmlns:pdfViewer="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer;assembly=Syncfusion.PdfViewer.WPF"
```

And this is how I have declared the Control inside a Grid:

```
<pdfViewer:PdfDocumentView Name="PdfViewer" AllowDrop="True"></pdfViewer:PdfDocumentView>
```

When I tried to run the application I got this error:

```
The name "PdfDocumentView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer;assembly=Syncfusion.PdfViewer.WPF".
```

Visual Studio autocompletes the Control declaration and attributes, and I am even able to see the preview from the XAML file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion PDF Viewer WPF is not supported in the client profile frameworks, please refer to the link [supported frameworks](http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdfviewer/overview), this might be the cause of this issue. Kindly switch the framework to get this issue resolved.

With reference to the [UG documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdfviewer/getting-started#create-a-simple-application-with-essential-pdf-viewer) the following assemblies are necessary for the inclusion of the PDF Viewer in an application.

- Syncfusion.Compression.Base
- Syncfusion.Core
- Syncfusion.Pdf.Base
- Syncfusion.PdfViewer.Wpf
- Syncfusion.Shared.Wpf

If you still face any issue in working with PDF Viewer, please contact Syncfusion support at support@syncfusion.com

Regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure assemblies being added are having same .Net version as your project's .Net version.

To check that right click on your project > Add > Reference..
In the Reference Manager window you can check Assembly's version, use SyncFusion documentation for assembly's supported .Net version.